# Save custom taxonomy data in different table not in wp_options for my own plugin

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I want to add taxonomy custom fields in different table in database but it will add in wp_options table which is not i want. And i have done this in my coding part.

```
function bookly_course_save_taxonomy_custom_meta( $term_id ) {
if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {

    $t_id = $term_id;
    $term_meta = get_option( "$t_id" );
    $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );
    foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ) {
        if ( isset ( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ) {
            $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
        }
    }
    // Save the option array.
    update_option( "$t_id", $term_meta );
}

}  
add_action( 'edited_bookly_course', 
'bookly_course_save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );  
add_action( 'create_bookly_course', 
'bookly_course_save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Use [`update_term_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/), not `update_option()`

Comment: I have an another question
how to show that custom field data with Name,Slug,Description on right side.

Comment: i think this would work by get_term_meta() but i am not sure with that.

Comment: Yes you'd retrieve the data with `get_term_meta()`

Comment: you have any idea about how to edit these custom fields which would be save in database.